# Android ButterKnife @OnClick() doesn`t work all dependency ok

Tags: android, butterknife

```
 @BindView(R.id.text_view)
TextView text_view;

@BindView(R.id.app_bar)
Toolbar toolbar;

 private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



}

@OnClick(R.id.test_btn)
void btnTest(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "all ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.calories, PID: 10164
>       java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #1 bootstrap method
>           at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:12)
>           at com.example.calories.MainActivity_ViewBinding.(MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:34)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
>           at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:170)
>           at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:99)
>           at com.example.calories.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)

Comment: Can you please post your xml layout file here too?

Answer (score 0):

Butter Knife requires that you enable Java 8 in your builds to function as of version 9.0.0 and newer. You can learn more about how to enable this at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.

You need to add something like

```
  android { 
compileOptions {
 targetCompatibility = "8" sourceCompatibility = "8"
 } 
}
```

to your application build.gradle.

Comment: Also, the latest version seems to be using Androidx components.